# Check property of List if it is of a given type

Tags: c#, linq, list, search, inheritance

I have this class structure

```
public class A
{
    int number;
}

public class B : A
{
    int otherNumber;
}
```

I want to search a list of `A` for items, where the `number` is greater than a given value and where the `otherNumber` is greater than another given value, if they are of type `B`. I am looking for something like:

```
var results = list.Where(x => x.number>5 && x.otherNumber>7).ToList();
```

Where `list` is a `List<A>`.

My current approach is:

```
var results = list.Where(x => x.number>5);
foreach(var result in results)
{
    B b = result As B;
    if(b!=null && b.otherNumber>7)
        [...]
}
```

Comment: You could write a custom comparer, or an overridable compare function, 5 and 7 are obviously not hard coded in real code, right? If you provided a description of the problem, rather than a problem with your attempted solution of an unknown problem, we could be more helpful.

Comment: You are right, the numbers are not hard coded. In fact they aren't even integers. I tried to write the problem as simple and easy as possible. I think the answer provided is a good approach and exactly what I need. More details: I try to find an `A` with the best properties in a list. Some of the `A`s have even more information, which can be considered, but I was not sure I could do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can filter by `number` field (assume fields are public). And then filter by `otherNumber` field if a is of `B` type. Otherwise second filtering will just skip

```
list.Where(a => a.number > 5).Where(a => !(a is B) || ((B)a).otherNumber > 7)
```

Maybe more readable way:

```
list.Where(a => {
   var b = a as B;
   return a.number > 5 && (b == null || b.otherNumber > 7);
})
```

Or query syntax

```
from a in list
let b = a as B
where a.number > 5 && (b == null || b.otherNumber > 7)
```

Comment: `!(a is B)` is a smart move in combination with the `||`. I like that. Do you think the two first approaches have a difference in performance?

Comment: @jasdefer: Performance is not a problem with the above code, readability is.

Comment: Do you know how this works with Entity Framework because `LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types`

Comment: @jasdefer EF is a different story. EF uses Expression instead of Func, and this expression should be able to be converted into SQL code. As error says to you, there is no equivalent of type casting in SQL language. With EF you can use `entities.Where(a => a.number > 5).Except(entities.OfType<B>().Where(b => b.otherNumber <= 7))`

Comment: You are awesome, thanks a lot. That makes sense. Sorry if I have another question: What if `B` is an interface? There is no compiler error if `B` is a child of `A`, but when it is an interface. In my case some children of `A` can implement an Interface. I want to check the property `otherNumber` if a child of `A` implement the interface. But the interface is an invalid argument (maybe because it is not really an entity). Maybe my structure is a little bit complicated :D

Comment: @jasdefer you can do filtering by number on server side, and then move any additional filtering to client. E.g. `entities.Where(a => a.number > 5).AsEnumerable().Where(...)`

Comment: `entities.Where(a => a.number > 5).AsEnumerable().Where(a => !(a is B) || ((B)a).otherNumber > 7)` is working fine :) thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Select all `B`s that aren't bigger than 7:

```
var badBs = list.OfType<B>().Where(x => x.otherNumber <= 7);
```

Select all items that match the first requirement, except those that don't match the second requirement:

```
var results = list.Where(x => x.number > 5).Except(badBs);
```

Comment: That is better than my approach, thank you for your answer. But I think the other answer is even better.

Answer (score 0):

Here - only B objects will be match condition, so most short form is:

```
list.OfType<B>().Where(x=>x.num1 > 5 && x.num2 < 7);
```

Comment: This will not delivere me only objects of type `B` and no `A`